# PHP Select form and if option matches something then make it selected

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a query like this:

```
while($stmt->fetch()){
    echo "<option value=\"".$sku_brandname."\">".$sku_brandname."</option>";
}
```

What I need to do is create a statement that says if sku_brandname = "Something" then make that one selected.

I'm not sure how to do that, because I can't create an if statement in the echo.

I tried something like this:

```
if($sku_brandname = "$brand") {
    $selected = " selected";
}
```

but can't quite get it to work, it shows all of them selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can make it in one line like this. I don't remember exactly what that statement is called

```
while($stmt->fetch()){
  $selected = ($sku_bandname == 'Something') ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
  echo '<option value="{$sku_brandname}" {$selected} >{$sku_brandname}</option>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason all of them get selected.  Am I doing something wrong?  $sku_brandname should equal $brand which is another string.

Comment: Are you hardcoding the 'Something' value or is it another variable? If it's another variable, check the value of that to make sure it's not the same as $sku_bandname

Comment: This should work:
echo "<option value=\"{$sku_brandname}\" {$selected} >{$sku_brandname}</option>";

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should do the job.

```
while($stmt->fetch()){
  if($sku_bandname == 'Something')
    $selected = ' selected="selected" ';
  else
    $selected = '';
  echo '<option value="{$sku_brandname}" {$selected} >{$sku_brandname}</option>';
}
```

Comment: P.R. Ribeiro You should never skip the {}'s even if there's only one line of code. That's just teaching bad practice